# Nautilus does not start from top menu

Tags: nautilus

I am experiencing very strange problems with nautilus in my Ubuntu linux. When I go to `Places` and click `Home Folder` (or any other nautilus item, a bookmark, for example), nautilus hangs at the bottom for a while and the dissapears - nothing gets opened:

[image: nautilus hangs]

However, if I type `nautilus` in command line, or open a folder from the Desktop, everything works fine.

I cannot recall when it has started, but it gets quite inconvinient. What could be causing this behavour? If it's hard to tell, then how can I diagnose/debug the problem?

I have used 10.10 and recently upgraded to 11.04 (it did not solve the problem)

Thank you!

Comment: If you upgraded to 11.04, are you using the Unity Launcher?

Comment: @Cas no, i've switched back to classic :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looks like a variant of this problem:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1151325

Comment: Actually, this solved the problem! I've opened a folder with "File browser" and everything is ok. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you have wrong file associations.

You may change the files associations at:

```
/usr/share/applications/defaults.list 
/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache
~/.local/share/applications/  
~/.gnome/share/apps/
```

Search in the files for:
`inode/directory`
`x-directory/normal`
`x-directory/gnome-default-handler`

Comment: You were right, associations were the problem, but Lorem, answer actually helped to solve it. Thank you for your effort!

Comment: I'm glad you could fix it.

Answer (score -1):

i cannot EXPLAIN this but i want to suggest a simple workaround:
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/04/how-to-add-folder-quicklists-to-the-home-launcher-in-ubuntu-unity/
it's all about editing /usr/share/applications/nautilus-home.desktop